# Is there a more elegant way to apply css to "all elements but this one"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html/jQuery that I am using to implement some tabbed navigation.  When a new tab is selected I need to make it's css class "active" and change the previous tabs css class to "inactive".  To do this I have been using the following code inside of my `click` event:

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
$("ul.tabs li").addClass("inactive");  //Set all to "inactive"
$(this).removeClass("inactive");  //remove "inactive" from the item that was clicked
$(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to the item that was clicked.
```

This works but I'm curious if anyone has found a cleaner/more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: you should probably chain your methods to be more elegant. That way, you do not call the jquery constructor 4 times, but only twice : `$().removeClass().addClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
});
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/4uMmc/

Comment: Bah, just a little bit quicker than me! =D

Comment: ooh, this looks promising.  I think I would have to change the last line to `$(this).removeClass().addClass("active");`

Comment: The reasoning for specifying a class name is for in the event that you have multiple classes attached to a specific <li> element.  But yes, you could easily remove it to remove ALL clases for that element.

Comment: There should be only inactive/active so I think your first version would work.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just have the `inactive` style be the default style? Then, you can just do this:

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Comment: hmmm, so a `li` would have both the `inactive` and the `active` class at the same time?  Will the styles clash with each other if I do that (sorry not a CSS expert)?

Comment: Yes, the li would have both classes, and the styles would probably clash. I forget which one wins. I think the last in the class list would. However, it is useful sometimes for an element to have multiple classes, just not in this case.

Comment: There is no real "clash" in CSS.  It's perfectly fine to have two classes on an object.  If both define different versions of the same style attribute, then the last one wins.  So, you just make the "active" rules be after the "inactive" rules in your CSS file and you should be fine.  If an object has both classes, the "active" rules will govern it which is what you want.

Comment: "If both define different versions of the same style attribute, then the last one wins." That's what I meant by clash. I guess override would have been a better word choice.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");`

Note, that it's better not to use `$('ul.tabs li')` in element's `click` event, so if you'd have many `.tabs` only the one where the clicked element is would be affected.

However, it's better to write CSS so you won't have to use `inactive` class, like this:

```
ul.tabs li {…} /* Inactive state */
ul.tabs li.active {…} /* Active state */
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply find elements with that class and then remove it? You could simplify that down to two lines:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
```

Answer (score 0):

This at least only evaluates the selectors once.

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
$(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
```

I agree with other suggestions, it's better to just get rid of the inactive class.  Make the default formatting for the tab be "inactive".  Then, just add/remove the active class as needed.  Put the CSS for the "active" class after the default CSS for the tabs and it will supercede the default state.  Then, your code could just be this:

```
$("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `:not()` is way faster than `.not()`
Also instead of adding and removing classes use jQuery [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
You should write the code just like this:

```
    $("ul.tabs li:not(" + $(this) + ")").toggleClass("active", "inactive");
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: This will not work. `:not` is only faster if you have a selector, but not a DOM element. You cannot concatenate a jQuery object this way anyway.

Comment: If this even works, it would toggle every inactive tab to be active which is not what is wanted.